# Installing wxPython on WSL (with GTK+2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, wxpython, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to install the `wxPython` package on the *Windows Subsystem for Linux* (with Ubuntu on Windows 10). First I tried to install it via `pip` like this:

```
python -m pip install wxpython
```

That fails during compilation, as it cannot find GTK+ libs. So I installed it via

```
apt install libgtk2.0-dev
```

which worked, but that did not help with my original task. The installation of `wxPython` still fails, since it needs GTK+3. But that is not available on WSL (via apt). So I wanted to build `wxPython` from source with the `--gtk2` flag. Now I am searching for the `wxPython` 4.0.7 sources, but can't find the at the moment ...

Has anyone successfully installed `wxPython` on WSL?

Comment: Sources for modules on `pypi` can usually be found [on the project page](https://pypi.org/project/wxPython/#files), just download the `.tar.gz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out that I had an old version of Ubuntu installed via WSL. After completely removing and re-installing the Ubuntu app via the Microsoft Windows store, I am now able to `apt install libgtk-3-dev && pip install wxpython`.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on WSL2 (Build 21343), Ubuntu 18.04
I tried your command above but it did not work for me.

This one did successfully install wxPython-4.1.1:
`python -m pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-18.04 wxPython`